# SQL server - update VARCHAR value to DECIMAL

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, decimal, varchar

Increase the rate by 10 percent of nurse resource in the resource table.
[image]

I try this code but fails

```
UPDATE Resourcetbl 
SET  Rate = convert(varchar(255), convert(decimal(10,2), Rate * 1.1))
WHERE ResName = 'nurse';
```

I get error message Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

---

Rate is VARCHAR(20)

Comment: I prefer syntax `CAST( rate AS DECIMAL(10,2) )` instead of convert.

Comment: You should store `rate` using the proper type, a numeric type.

Comment: Yes you are right, but table was already created so i cannot change it

Answer (score 1):

Convert `Rate` to `decimal` before multiply:

```
UPDATE Resourcetbl 
SET  Rate = convert(varchar(255), convert(decimal(10,2),Rate) * 1.1)
WHERE ResName = 'nurse';
```

Comment: is not working >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '22.000' to data type int.

Comment: I think you dont know what you want

Comment: @DraganSekuloski add sample data where it does not work

Comment: As i mention before I try to Increase the rate by 10 percent of nurse resource in the resource table. but the Rate is VARCHAR(20) and it was giving me a problem

Comment: @DraganSekuloski this code is working for data you provided. Maybe, somwhere you have not a number in `Rate` column

Comment: Rate have following values bellow and they are numbers:
10
15
10
20
15
10 >>> i receive this error msg Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '22.000' to data type int. >>>> I assume maybe for this case is not needed to convert the rate and SQL Server recognize the number inside the varchar and make calculation without any additional converting

Comment: @DraganSekuloski in my code there is no convertions to `int`, only `decimal`. check your code

Answer (score 0):

Because you must convert to decimal your value before arithmetic operation

```
convert(varchar(255), (convert(decimal(10,2), Rate) * 1.1))
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '22.000' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAST

```
UPDATE Resourcetbl 
SET  Rate = convert(varchar(255),CAST(rate AS DECIMAL(9,2)) * 1.1))
WHERE ResName = 'nurse';
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '22.000' to data type int.

Comment: @DraganSekuloski:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: is not working Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '24.200' to data type int. -- thanks for the effort, >>>>>>>> >>>>>>>> finally this work  UPDATE Resourcetbl 
SET  Rate += (Rate*10)/100
WHERE ResName = 'nurse';

Answer (score 0):

unexpecting - this do the job

UPDATE Resourcetbl 
SET  Rate += (Rate*10)/100
WHERE ResName = 'nurse';